# Mercadopago - Error al crear un token de uso único - com.mercadopago:services:1.0.1

Tags: android, mercadopago

Estoy solicitando un token de uso único y siempre obtengo el siguiente error:

`Error Message: invalid location` 
`Error: bad_request`
`Status - 400`

El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

Libreria:

`compile 'com.mercadopago:services:1.0.1'`

Creación del CardToken

```
Identification identification = new Identification();        
identification.setNumber("12345678");
identification.setType("CI-V");

Cardholder cardholder = new Cardholder();
cardholder.setIdentification(identification);
cardholder.setName("PEDRO");

CardToken mCardToken = new CardToken();
mCardToken.setCardholder(cardholder);
mCardToken.setCardNumber("4111111111111111");
mCardToken.setDevice(ProcessingPaymentActivity.this);
mCardToken.setExpirationMonth(12);
mCardToken.setExpirationYear(2018);
mCardToken.setSecurityCode("123");
```

Solicitud del token:

```
mMercadoPagoServices.createToken(mCardToken, new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void success(@NonNull Token token) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Card token = " + token.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(@NonNull ApiException error) {

            Log.e(TAG, "requestCardToken Error: "+error.getMessage()+" - error: "+error.getError()+" - status - "+error.getStatus());

        }
    });
```

Gracias

Comment: Tuviste respuesta? Tengo el mismo error con la doc de esta pagina: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/charge-with-creditcard/android/

Comment: No continua el problema, antes me funcionaba correctamente y ahora da ese error de "invalid location"

Comment: Seguis sin solucion?

Comment: Nada y en la documentación la he revisado varias veces, pero no he visto nada referente a ese mensaje

Comment: El canal de soporte para desarrolladores de mercado pago es developers@mercadopago.com

Comment: Roberto @JpCrow pueden revisar este issue donde se discute el caso https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android_services/issues/9

Comment: a mi también me sale el mismo error al intentar crear un token para tarjeta, en mi caso, desactivando el GPS funciona correctamente la creación del token pero cuando está activo el GPS me devuelve **invalid location**, puede ser que haya un bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema fue solucionado por el equipo de desarrollo de mercadopago, era un BUG que se encontraba del lado de su plataforma.